# Parametrise a Cylinder

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, geometry, multivariable-calculus, vector-spaces

I have a cylinder of equation $x^2+y^2=R^2$ where $z$ ranges from $0$ to $h$.

How would I parameterise this? I want to right $r=(R\cos(\theta),R\sin(\theta),)$ but then I can't write $z=z$ because I would have $3$ variables rather than $2$.

Comment: What you have is sufficient. Compare it to $x=1$ in the plane. When we write an equation to describe a locus of points, we are writing the restrictions. Therefore, $\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb R^3: x^2+y^2=R^2\}$ describes the cylinder.

Comment: Yes, $z=z$.$ R $ isn’t a variable, it’s a constant

Comment: No, not $z=z$. That doesn't say anything. Every point in space satisfies $z=z$ so it is redundant. For cylindrical coordinates you have that the cylinder $C=\{(r,\theta, z): r=R\text{ and }0\le z\le h\}$. Theta is free to take all values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use a single parameter since single parameters give curves not surfaces

The closest thing I can think of is
[cylindrical coordinates](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&opi=89978449&url=https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cylindrical_coordinate_system&ved=2ahUKEwjZ4_ro8NeDAxXBcGwGHVzWDUkQFnoECCcQAQ&usg=AOvVaw2RBYxHOksiYDRps874tJvF)

Or in other words parameterizing the circle and height separatly

PS. You could prolly make a single parameter using space filling curves but that is a totally different can of worms

Comment: If you want to parameterize the inside of the cylinder you def need 3 since its just a continuation of 2d polar coordinates (well one of the continuations spherical coordinates are also heavily used)